# Change ListBox css attribute at runtime

Tags: gwt

I have a ListBox:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
```

this is my default css for a listbox:

```
.gwt-ListBox {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  color: #555;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:arial;
  height: 40px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to modify the background at runtime:

```
lb.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#aaa");
```

this seems to remove all styling, and I get a really ugly listbox. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A working and more maintainable way of doing this is using a CSS client bundle, see:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html

and

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html

Put the parts of the style that you want to vary in a CssResource and apply the extra style. To give you an idea of how to do this:

MyWidget.css:

```
.backgroundA {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

MyWidget.java:

```
interface MyWidgetCssResource extends CssResource {
  String backgroundA();
}

MyWidgetCssResource resource;

lb.getElement().addStyleNames(resource.backgroundA());
```